# Publishing web project fails when custom output folder is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, typescript, web-publishing

A web project that includes typescript and makes use of the "Redirect Javascript output to folder" option can currently not be published (local file system) because Microsoft.TypeScript.targets does not honor TypeScriptOutDir when populating FilesForPackagingFromProject and/or other MSBuild variables.

This is a small snippet extracted from my .csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>amd</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptOutDir>$(ProjectDir)Scripts\ts</TypeScriptOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The offending option is TypeScriptOutDir. If I remove it, publishing works as expected.

Did anyone else experience the same problem and has comeup with a work-around? I don't care if a fix would involve editing Microsoft.TypeScript.targets.

Comment: I've seen this - did you solve it?